# upon backgrid:edited event mode does not have changed attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-select2, backgrid

I am using backbone and `backgrid` and also using `backgrid` select2 extension.

When i change the backgrid cell, and add some list item from `select2`, upon consoling before `model.save` i get `model.changed` with no properties and also `model._previousAttributes` and `model.attributes` properties are exactly same.

How do i find changed attribute and and which list item from `select2` is added or removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access them using [Backbone.Model#changedAttributes](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes).